# newline sensitive interpretation of Arrays

Tags: julia

When I add a newline to my array definition, the type of my array changes.

```
julia> a = [[1]]
1-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1]

julia> a = [[1]

       ]
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
```

I thought they both should return the same result i.e. of type `Array{Array{Int64,1},1}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to understand this see the following:

```
julia> :([[1]

         ])
:([[1];])
```

And you see that adding a newline is rewritten as `vcat` operation.

The reason for this is to allow writing something like this:

```
julia> x = [1 2
            3 4]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4
```

and your example is hitting a corner case of this syntax.

Note, however, that without an extra empty line `vcat` is not called:

```
julia> :([[1]
         ])
:([[1]])
```

Another use-case that is worth to know is:

```
julia> [[1, 2]
        [3, 4]]
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

and the same with variables (can improve code readability in some cases):

```
julia> a = [1,2]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2

julia> b = [3, 4]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 4

julia> [a
        b]
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
```